# ramda update object value base on original value

Tags: ramda.js

I want to update the `path` in object with prefix `http://127.0.0.1`
Which method should I use in Ramda?

```
  const data = [
    { id: 1, path: '/abc/1.jpg' },
    { id: 2, path: '/abc/2.jpg' },
    { id: 3, path: '/abc/1.jpg' },
  ];

  // ES6 way
  const R1 = data.map(item => {
    return {
      ...item,
      path: `http://127.0.0.1${item.path}`
    }
  });
```

I try to use `R.assoc` to replace the value.
But I don't know how can I get the original path value
Please guide me.

```
  // Ramda way ??
  const R2 = R.map(
    R.assoc('path', 'http://127.0.0.1'), 
    data
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two fairly simple ways to do this point-free.  There are many ones that are not point-free as well.

The first one looks like this:

```js
const {map, over, lensProp, concat} = R

const transform = map(over(lensProp('path'), concat('http://127.0.0.1')))


const data = [{"id": 1, "path": "/abc/1.jpg"},
              {"id": 2, "path": "/abc/2.jpg"}, 
              {"id": 3, "path": "/abc/1.jpg"}]
console.log(transform(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

The second one looks like this:

```js
const {map, evolve, concat} = R

const transform = map(evolve({path: concat('http://127.0.0.1')}))

const data = [{"id": 1, "path": "/abc/1.jpg"}, 
              {"id": 2, "path": "/abc/2.jpg"}, 
              {"id": 3, "path": "/abc/1.jpg"}]
console.log(transform(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

The first approach uses more standard FP tools: lenses.  It will be more recognizable to folks coming from other languages or libraries.

The second approach has the advantage that it's a bit more robust when the data is not precisely what you want.  And if you wanted to add other transformations, there would not be chained calls but only additional elements in the the specification passed to `evolve`.

And of course if you wanted to forgo point-free, you could just use

```
const transform = map(item => assoc('path', 'http://123.0.0.1' + item.path, item))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I really learned a lot!! I can understand ramda function seperately. But when I need to use them. I don't know how to compose them. Thanks again